# MDM push notifications while guided mode is running?

Tags: ios, notifications, push, mdm

I need to install an enterprise app through MDM.

My MDM implementation generally works.

But if I use the guided mode, the push notifications aren't delivered to the devices running in guided mode so the app won't be installed. Why?

Is this generally possible?

Is there a way to install an app in a silent enforced way (without the "The server will install application... do you want it?" alert).

I actually need an update process like following:

1. App x is running, but needs to be updated. Because it is a kiosk device (iPad running the app x in guided mode), it should happen automatically without user interaction. There may be interaction by a customer using that kiosk device.
2. The app x is closing itself and changes to app y that shows a lock screen "Maintenance, please wait..." (i.e. a notification from my server and through a trick with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:xxx]`)
3. App x has been closed in step 2 is updating by MDM in background.
4. App x has finished being updated.
5. A signal will be send to app y so it will switch back to the updated app x.

The switching between x and y can be implemented directly into the code. This is not a problem. 
But I stuck in sending the push notification that initiates this process. :-(

Comment: Hi, Franky. I have a same issue. Could you tell me, did you solve it?